# How to grab number/float from a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the (first) price of each string row, with out the $ sign and it could be an int or float and there could be more numbers in the row.

example:

```
$str_array=(
"Up to $1.9 per Install in RU",
"1.3 per iOS Install in UAE and SA",
"$2.1 per iOS and Android Registration in US",
"Up to $2.5 per Android Install in 7 countries",
"Up to $1 per iOS Install in SA"
);
```

**Expected output:**

```
1.9
1.3
2.1
2.5
1
```

I tried something like this

```
$re = '/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/';
$str = 'Up to $2.5 per Android Install in 7 countries';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

and i get this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2.5
        [1] => 2.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
    )
```

but its not working good. :(

Comment: define `not working good`

Comment: How are you using this? You aren't looking for a `$`, is that required? Maybe you want `[+-]?\$(\d*\.)?\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'Up to $1.9 per Install in RU',
    '1.3 per iOS Install in UAE and SA',
    '$2.1 per iOS and Android Registration in US',
    'Up to $2.5 per Android Install in 7 countries',
    'Up to $1 per iOS Install in SA'
];

array_walk($data, function(&$line){
    preg_match('/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/', $line, $tokens);
    if (count($tokens)>1) {
        var_dump(floatval($tokens[1]));
    }
});
```

The output obviously is:

```
float(1.9)
float(1.3)
float(2.1)
float(2.5)
float(1)
```

Comment: won't work for this entry `'Up to 7 per Android Install in $2.5 countries'`. The OP wanted price value

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That is true, _but_: that is impossible to solve, since the OP explicitly wrote that the value can occur _without_ currency sign (see second row in the example). If at all you' d have to implement a preference algorithm and I seriously doubt that is the topic of this question.

Comment: @arkascha, I suppose, he meant: "I want to match the first price value(with $ sign)" but to output it *without the $ sign*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Still the question remains: how would you decide what number is the "price"? That is not solvable in a definite way. It makes no sense to invest in that in my eyes. Also a number _with_ a currency sign might _not_ be the price mentioned in a line...

Comment: @arkascha, I don't think so, I see no unified answers here, I hoped you would improve your solution

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out,

**Regex:** `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

> **1.** `\d+` this will match digits
>
> **2.** `(?:\.\d+)?` this will optionally match decimal part

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785155)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$str_array=array(
"Up to $1.9 per Install in RU",
"1.3 per iOS Install in UAE and SA",
"$2.1 per iOS and Android Registration in US",
"Up to $2.5 per Android Install in 7 countries",
"Up to $1 per iOS Install in SA"
);
$result=array();
foreach($str_array as $string)
{
    preg_match_all('/[\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?/',$string,$matches);
    $result[]=$matches[0][0];
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.9
    [1] => 1.3
    [2] => 2.1
    [3] => 2.5
    [4] => 1
)
```

Comment: You select `7` in the line before the last one in the example

Comment: @sortof I know you got your expected result, I have updated my post with your expected result

Answer (score 0):

To select only the first number in a line add condition that there is no digit before

```
^(?:[^\d]+)([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)
```

**[demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/XDwswo/3)**

Comment: it doesnt catch the float number

Comment: @sortof You are right. I don't test OP's expression :)